# Calculating change in gravitational potential energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity, space, potential-energy, satellites

A satellite mass $500\ kg$ is elevated from altitude $10000\ km$ to altitude $20000\ km$. Radius of earth is $6378\ km$. Mass of earth is $5.97 \cdot 10^{24}\ kg$. Gravity is given to be $9.81\ m/s $

My attempt is using final $mgh$ - initial $mgh$.

initial $mgh = 500 \cdot 9.8 \cdot (16378 \cdot 1000)$

final $mgh = 500 \cdot 9.8 \cdot (26378 \cdot 1000)$

Final - initial I get $4.9 \cdot 10^{10}$

The correct answer is $4.61 \cdot 10^9$

Were did I go wrong?

Comment: Please not that Physics.StackEchange is not a homework help site; see [this meta post on "check my work problems"](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093) as well as [the homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/715/25301).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: You're far enough from the ground that the formula $mgh$, which is an approximation, doesn't really apply anymore. What is the true formula for gravitational potential energy?

Comment: So you are saying I have to use -g(m1m2 / r)?

Much thanks! I will be able to try this tomorrow.